# How to get receipt per transaction in IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my ios app, I have a couple of consumables available.

I do server side transaction receipt validation, so I notice that if my server was down, the transactions will not get validated (duh). At that point, I do not "finish" the transaction in the client side app.

The next time app launches, the ios system will loop through the none finished transactions, and then I loop through them one by one via

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {/* Validate receipt for each transaction. */}
```

The issue is, since I validate the transactions one by one, but I get the receipt via

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

The receipt will contain all the transactions made. So I can't tell which transaction the receipt is covering for.

Is there a way to get the transaction receipt for only one given transaction? the transactionReceipt property seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up sending the whole receipt to the server side for each transaction.

The server is able to tell which transactions the receipt is covered for.